# Stuck on proof of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{7}{4} - \frac{1}{n}$ for $n \geq 3$ using induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, induction, proof-explanation

I'm relatively familiar with induction, I'm just stuck on this step. I am currently taking Introduction to Abstract Math, and have taken Calculus I and II.

$P(n)$ is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{7}{4} - \frac{1}{n}$$
Prove *P(n)* is true for all $n, \{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ | \: n \geq 3 \}$

**Basis Step**

Show that $P(3)$ is true.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{3} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{7}{4} - \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2}\leq \frac{7}{4} - \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{49}{36} \leq \frac{17}{12}$$
$\frac{49}{36} \leq \frac{17}{12}$ is true, therefore $P(3)$ is true.

**Induction Step**

Assume $P(n)$ is true for some $n, \{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ | \: n \geq 3 \}$. Show that $P(n+1)$ holds true, with $P(n+1)$ being defined as $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{7}{4} - \frac{1}{n+1}$.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{7}{4} - \frac{1}{n}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \leq \frac{7}{4} - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$
That's where I got stuck. What would be the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}\le\frac74-\frac1n+\frac1{(n+1)^2}\,,\tag{1}$$

and you want to show that lefthand side of $(1)$ is at most $\frac74-\frac1{n+1}$; the most straightforward way to do this is to show that

$$\frac74-\frac1n+\frac1{(n+1)^2}\le\frac74-\frac1{n+1}\,,$$

which amounts to showing that

$$\frac1{(n+1)^2}\le\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\,.$$

And since $\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}=\frac1{n(n+1)}$, this is clear.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac 1 {k^{2}}$$ $$ =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac 1 {k^{2}}+\frac 1 {(n+1)^{2}}$$ $$ \leq \frac 7 4 -\frac 1 n +\frac 1 {(n+1)^{2}}$$ $$ \leq \frac 7 4 -\frac 1 n +\frac 1 {n(n+1)}$$ $$ =\frac 7 4 -\frac 1 n +\left[\frac 1 n-\frac 1 {(n+1)}\right]$$ $$ \leq \frac 7 4 -\frac 1 {n+1}.$$

Comment: How did you get $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ from $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$?

Comment: @CalypsoRivers $n(n+1) <(n+1)(n+1) $ so $\frac 1 {n(n+1)} > \frac1  {(n+1)^{2}}$